# How to run test (Gherkin's tagged scenarios) using junit in command prompt?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I have a Gherkin script in IntelliJ with several Scenarios under a Feature. 
The general structure looks like this:

```
Feature AAA
    @sample tag
    Scenario A

    @anothertag
    Scenario B

    @thirdtag
    Scenario C
```

Each Scenario is essentially a test case that I want to test, and is given a unique tag. 
I want to run a specific test case from the command prompt by referencing the tag of that test case (eg scenario). For simplicity, let's say I give my scenario A a tag named "sampletag".
Note: I use junit 4.12 to execute the test case from the command prompt.

Problem: I keep getting the same error message java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [sampletag]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sampletag

I have tried looking at the path to my .jar file and include that path in the command. 
I also have a suspicion that the way I reference the tag (of the scenario) is incorrect.
Please see my command prompt for additional info.

```
C:\Users\Myself> java -cp fileA\repo\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore sampletag
```

The error I'm getting after pressing Enter on the command prompt with that above code is:

```
    There was 1 failure:
    1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [sampletag]
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sampletag
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
            at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
            ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: Do you run test manually from command line or use IDE? Based on the command you pass only junit jar to classpath and no project classes - java will not find them. See also https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-cucumber-tests.html#878a7c29

Comment: u need to use a cucumber runner(cucumber.api.cli.Main) instead of a junit runner. Refer to this https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#from-the-command-line